# How to easily access docker container when using AWS ECS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I'm testing a solution of hosting an Ruby on Rails application in Elastic Container Service(ECS). I made the setup without Fargate and have my application running.

The thing is, whenever I have to enter the rails console, it is necessary to ssh one of the cluster instances, run a docker ps to list the containers, copy the container ID and use it in the `docker exec -it <container_id> rails c`

Do anyone know of a way to make it easier? Something like accessing the container without the need to query the container id or any other shortcut? Would Fargate help in this issue?

Comment: I'm not a rails guy, did you try AWS cli command like `aws ecs describe-tasks`

Comment: You can type the container id for 1 or 2 characters if it is unique. For example, there is only one container with id somehow `46dkr6f83c4` then you can type only `4`.

Answer (score 0):

You can name your container in task definition and use that name to 'exec'. You wont need container-id in this case. Assuming you have only one container running i.e no scaling.